# AVRO serialize a c# class with a constructor

Tags: c#, avro

My goal is to be able to avro serialize a c# class.
I'm currently trying to use `Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro` to serialize but I can't seem to get it to work as my application throws an exception `'Type 'Animals.Horse' is not supported by the resolver.'`. Do you have any idea how to do it right?

`Program.cs`:

```
      AvroSerializerSettings settings = new AvroSerializerSettings();
      settings.Resolver = new AvroPublicMemberContractResolver();
      var result = AvroSerializer.Create<Horse>(settings).WriterSchema.ToString();
```

`Horse.cs`:

```
namespace Animals
{
    public class Horse
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Horse(string name)
        {
            Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:
I am aware of this thread:
https://www.thecodebuzz.com/avro-serializationexception-type-is-not-supported-by-the-resolver-microsoft-hadoop-avro/
but he's not using a `constructor` in his domain class. For me it doesn't throw the exception if there wasn't a `constructor` or if the `constructor` was empty...

Comment: If it works without the constructor, then the likelihood is the serialiser requires a parameterless constructor in order to create an instance. You may get away with adding a `private` parameterless constructor.

Comment: It is fairly common for serialization libraries to require public parameterless constructor and public setters. One way to handle this is to use a separate `HorseDto` class just for serialization, and do all the validation in your real `Horse` class. Using separate classes can also be convenient if the data changes.